# Differential Equation Application of Physics-Sliding Block

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, applications

Where I can I start to solve this question?

A block is released with an initial velocity v0 = 20 m/s from the bottom of an inclined plane
making an angle of 30◦ with the horizontal. If the constant of friction is µ = 0:4, find the displacement
of the block ignoring air resistance (g = 10 m/s2)

[Question Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KirZ9.png)

Comment: I couldn't get any aswer in this link.

Comment: Just use energy method to solve it. Or consider that its acceleration is constant and use $\vec x=\vec v_0 t + \frac 1 2 \vec a t^2$. There is no need for ODE.  Maybe go to Physics.SE for more help